# How to perform a rake task after startup?

Tags: startup, root

I'm using Rails, and I'd like to perform a specific rake task on boot. I've made a shell script like so:

```
cd /path/to/my/app
rake db:backup
```

which is symlinked in `/etc/rc2.d/`. The problem is that the script is run as root which means it doesn't have access to rake (I'm using bundler and rvm). I'd like to change to my user for the script, but can't work out how to do that successfully.

So, is there a way to make this run as my account, or is there a better way to get the rake task run after startup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add something like

```
if [ "$(id -nu)" != 'your_user' ]; then
  exec sudo -u 'your_user' $0
fi
```

at the beginning of the script.

Comment: If I run my script with `sudo` (I assume this has the same affect as it being run by root at startup) then I get `rake: not found`.

Comment: Try adding the `-H` (home) option to `sudo`.

Comment: Still not working - please see my new question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/43881/how-to-get-rvm-working-when-run-from-a-startup-script

Comment: "sudo -u user" runs a command as user "user". If you use "sudo -u user -i" sudo runs the given command in a login shell, i.e. you get the same environment as if you login in text mode. Usually it's better to provide the needed environment vars, like $PATH, in your shell script.

Comment: Great, adding the `-i` option did it, thanks.