# How to get RVM working when run from a startup script

Tags: startup, rvm

Ok, following on from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43863/how-to-perform-a-rake-task-after-startup), I'm still having problems getting things working. I'm doing this:

```
if [ "$(id -nu)" != 'your_user' ]; then
  exec sudo -Hu 'your_user' $0
fi
which ruby
cd /path/to/my/app
rake db:backup
```

The problem is, `which ruby` is printing `/usr/bin/ruby`, but when I run it in a normal bash session I get `/home/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby`, because I'm using RVM. So `rake` doesn't work because it's working from the wrong Ruby installation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like [Florian sorted this on the linked question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43863/how-to-perform-a-rake-task-after-startup/43866#43866)

```
sudo -u 'user_name' -i
```

"runs the given command in a login shell, i.e. you get the same environment as if you login in text mode."

Comment: ``-H`` is not needed as ``-i`` does that already.

Comment: @Florian - Thanks for the clarification. This is all just magic spells for me at the moment :P